# id: null issue in sailsJS when create an User

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I suspect my issue is something silly, but I can't find the error. I'm using mongodb to persist user data. Every seems to work fine but when I look the database I have `id: null` in every user record.
I don't want that `id: null`, I already have `_id` field.

```
$sails --version
0.11.0
```

My userController:

```
module.exports = {
  create: function(req, res) {
    User.create(req.params.all(), function userCreated(err, user) {
      if(err) res.json(401, err);
      res.json(200, user);
    })
  }
}
```

My user model:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    email: {
      type: 'string',
      email: true,
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    password: {
      type: 'string',
      minLength: 6,
      maxLength: 15,
      columnName: 'encrypted_password',
      required: true
    },
    toJSON: function() {
      var obj = this.toObject();
      delete obj.password;
      return obj;
    }
  },
  beforeCreate: function(values, next) {
    require('bcrypt').hash(values.password, 10, function passwordEncrypted(err, encryptedPassword) {
      if(err) console.log(err);
      values.password = encryptedPassword;
      next();
    });
  }
};
```

When I create a user from url like `http://localhost:1337/user/create?name=theUser&email=user@mail.com&password=123456&role=admin` everythink seems to be fine but in my mongodb I see this: (`id: null`)

```
{
    name: "theUser",
    email: "user@mail.com",
    role: "admin",
    id: null,
    createdAt: ISODate("2015-04-27T18:34:42.678Z"),
    updatedAt: ISODate("2015-04-27T18:34:42.678Z"),
    encrypted_password: "$2a$10$iNt/OR8XhjijqRjkpoNW/eR70HTSDgVJ2WmNppqab79rZt213aywm",
    _id: ObjectId("553e81429255e51f419a8ffc")
}
```

I'd tried with `autoPK: false` but nothing happens.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try with schema:true on your model . . . just a thought. Also if console.log(values) on your before create, what do you see?

Comment: Its weird, my `console.log(values)` in `beforeCreate` shows `id: null`, but the response in UserController->create is `id: "553fa7e9ed01d3711d56360b"` In this JSON the id field is exactly what I want... is the `_id` in MongoDB database...

Comment: in `afterCreate` function id field is correct but in MongoDB `id: null`...

Comment: I solve the problem: `autoPK: false, schema: true` is the solution. The lack of `autoPK: false` or `schema: true` provokes `id: null`.

Thank you Meeker!

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [waterline docs](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models.md),

> By default an attribute named id will be automatically added to your
>   model which will contain an auto-incrementing number unique to each
>   record. This will be your model's primary key and will be indexed when
>   available. You can override this if you would like to define your own
>   primary key factory or attribute.

**primaryKey**

Will set the primary key of the record. This should be used when `autoPK` is set to false.

```
attributes: {
  uuid: {
    type: 'string',
    primaryKey: true,
    required: true
  }
}
```